# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize Help needed

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.ios, json.net

Can anyone help to write Newtonsoft JSON Deserializer for my JSON format.

I have following json format.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Missing ajax operation. Please contact administrator.",
    "data": {
        "mode": "new",
        "data": {
            "1": {
                "CustomerCode": "CUST00001",
                "Name": "Dell Asia Pacific Sdn. Bhd.",
                "Add1": "Plot 76 Mukim 11, Bukit Tengah Industrial Park; Bukit Mertajam; Pulau Pinang; 14000",
                "Add2": "",
                "Add3": "",
                "Daddr1": "Level 21, Suite 21.01, The Gardens South Tower, Mid Valley City, Lingkaran Syed Putra, ; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 59200",
                "Daddr2": "",
                "Daddr3": "",
                "Attn": "",
                "Phone": "",
                "PhoneA": "",
                "Fax": "",
                "Area": "",
                "Agent": "",
                "Email": "",
                "CurrCode": "MYR",
                "Business": "",
                "Term": "30 Days"
            },
            "2": {
                "CustomerCode": "CUST00002",
                "Name": "Intel Technology Sdn Bhd",
                "Add1": "Bayan Lepas Free Industrial Zone,Phase 3,Halaman Kampung Jawa; Bayan Lepas; Pulau Pinang; 11900",
                "Add2": "",
                "Add3": "",
                "Daddr1": "1st Flr,Standard Chartered Bank Chambers,Lebuh Pantai;Penang; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 10300",
                "Daddr2": "",
                "Daddr3": "",
                "Attn": "",
                "Phone": "",
                "PhoneA": "",
                "Fax": "",
                "Area": "",
                "Agent": "",
                "Email": "",
                "CurrCode": "MYR",
                "Business": "",
                "Term": "30 Days"
            },
            "3": {
                "CustomerCode": "CUST00003",
                "Name": "Petronas Carigali Sdn. Bhd.",
                "Add1": "Tower 1, Petronas Twin Towers,Kuala Lumpur City Centre,; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 50088",
                "Add2": "",
                "Add3": "",
                "Daddr1": "Tower 1,Petronas Twin Towers,K.L.City Centre; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 50088",
                "Daddr2": "",
                "Daddr3": "",
                "Attn": "",
                "Phone": "",
                "PhoneA": "",
                "Fax": "",
                "Area": "",
                "Agent": "",
                "Email": "",
                "CurrCode": "MYR",
                "Business": "",
                "Term": "30 Days"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have following Class structure

```
public class CustomerInfo
        {
            public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Add1 { get; set; }
            public string Add2 { get; set; }
            public string Add3 { get; set; }
            public string Daddr1 { get; set; }
            public string Daddr2 { get; set; }
            public string Daddr3 { get; set; }
            public string Attn { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
            public string PhoneA { get; set; }
            public string Fax { get; set; }
            public string Area { get; set; }
            public string Agent { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string CurrCode { get; set; }
            public string Business { get; set; }
            public string Term { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerData
        {
            public CustomerInfo customerInfo { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public string mode { get; set; }
            public CustomerData custdata { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerRootObject
        {
            public bool success { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public Data data { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I have difficulties to parse this json format I wrote following but it is not working any help much appreciated.

```
List<CustomerRootObject> customerlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerRootObject>> (json);

foreach (var info in customerlist) {Console.WriteLine(info.data.custdata.CustomerCode);}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am not getting parsing issue but foreach  is not getting invoked.

Comment: You should probably debug it and see what is going on. Question though, why are you deserializing to `List<CustomerRootObject>`instead of just CustomerRootObject?

Comment: Basically, I want to get list of CustomerInfo information. What do you mean instead of just CustomerRootObject. I am a bit new in c#. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your JSON is not formed correctly (or you class doesn't have the correct structure). Which one can you change?

First, like @Tobberoth said, you should not be deserializing to a list.

```
    CustomerRootObject customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerRootObject> (json)
```

You "list" of data is not at the CustomerRootObject level - it is at the CustomerInfo level.

```
    public class CustomerData
    {
        public List<CustomerInfo> customerInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, you need to change this class:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public CustomerData data { get; set; }
    }
```

Your JSON property is called data. You need to change one or the other.

Comment: Also no need to change the JSON property name or the class name. As highlighted in Brian Rogers' answer, you can simply decorate the class attribute with [JsonProperty("data")]

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because your class structure doesn't match the JSON.

Try changing your `Data` class to this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string mode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<int, CustomerInfo> customers { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize like this:

```
CustomerRootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerRootObject>(json);
```

You can list out the customers like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CustomerInfo> kvp in obj.data.customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("----- Customer " + kvp.Key + " -----");
    Console.WriteLine("CustomerCode: " + kvp.Value.CustomerCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + kvp.Value.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Add1: " + kvp.Value.Add1.Replace(";", "\r\n"));
}
```

Full demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""success"": true,
            ""message"": ""Missing ajax operation. Please contact administrator."",
            ""data"": {
                ""mode"": ""new"",
                ""data"": {
                    ""1"": {
                        ""CustomerCode"": ""CUST00001"",
                        ""Name"": ""Dell Asia Pacific Sdn. Bhd."",
                        ""Add1"": ""Plot 76 Mukim 11, Bukit Tengah Industrial Park; Bukit Mertajam; Pulau Pinang; 14000"",
                        ""Add2"": """",
                        ""Add3"": """",
                        ""Daddr1"": ""Level 21, Suite 21.01, The Gardens South Tower, Mid Valley City, Lingkaran Syed Putra, ; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 59200"",
                        ""Daddr2"": """",
                        ""Daddr3"": """",
                        ""Attn"": """",
                        ""Phone"": """",
                        ""PhoneA"": """",
                        ""Fax"": """",
                        ""Area"": """",
                        ""Agent"": """",
                        ""Email"": """",
                        ""CurrCode"": ""MYR"",
                        ""Business"": """",
                        ""Term"": ""30 Days""
                    },
                    ""2"": {
                        ""CustomerCode"": ""CUST00002"",
                        ""Name"": ""Intel Technology Sdn Bhd"",
                        ""Add1"": ""Bayan Lepas Free Industrial Zone,Phase 3,Halaman Kampung Jawa; Bayan Lepas; Pulau Pinang; 11900"",
                        ""Add2"": """",
                        ""Add3"": """",
                        ""Daddr1"": ""1st Flr,Standard Chartered Bank Chambers,Lebuh Pantai;Penang; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 10300"",
                        ""Daddr2"": """",
                        ""Daddr3"": """",
                        ""Attn"": """",
                        ""Phone"": """",
                        ""PhoneA"": """",
                        ""Fax"": """",
                        ""Area"": """",
                        ""Agent"": """",
                        ""Email"": """",
                        ""CurrCode"": ""MYR"",
                        ""Business"": """",
                        ""Term"": ""30 Days""
                    },
                    ""3"": {
                        ""CustomerCode"": ""CUST00003"",
                        ""Name"": ""Petronas Carigali Sdn. Bhd."",
                        ""Add1"": ""Tower 1, Petronas Twin Towers,Kuala Lumpur City Centre,; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 50088"",
                        ""Add2"": """",
                        ""Add3"": """",
                        ""Daddr1"": ""Tower 1,Petronas Twin Towers,K.L.City Centre; Kuala Lumpur; Wilayah Persekutuan; 50088"",
                        ""Daddr2"": """",
                        ""Daddr3"": """",
                        ""Attn"": """",
                        ""Phone"": """",
                        ""PhoneA"": """",
                        ""Fax"": """",
                        ""Area"": """",
                        ""Agent"": """",
                        ""Email"": """",
                        ""CurrCode"": ""MYR"",
                        ""Business"": """",
                        ""Term"": ""30 Days""
                    }
                }
            }
        }";

        CustomerRootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerRootObject>(json);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CustomerInfo> kvp in obj.data.customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----- Customer " + kvp.Key + " -----");
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerCode: " + kvp.Value.CustomerCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + kvp.Value.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Add1: " + kvp.Value.Add1.Replace(";", "\r\n"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress a key to Exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public class CustomerInfo
    {
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Add1 { get; set; }
        public string Add2 { get; set; }
        public string Add3 { get; set; }
        public string Daddr1 { get; set; }
        public string Daddr2 { get; set; }
        public string Daddr3 { get; set; }
        public string Attn { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string PhoneA { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Agent { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CurrCode { get; set; }
        public string Business { get; set; }
        public string Term { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string mode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Dictionary<int, CustomerInfo> customers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerRootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
----- Customer 1 -----
CustomerCode: CUST00001
Name: Dell Asia Pacific Sdn. Bhd.
Add1: Plot 76 Mukim 11, Bukit Tengah Industrial Park
 Bukit Mertajam
 Pulau Pinang
 14000
----- Customer 2 -----
CustomerCode: CUST00002
Name: Intel Technology Sdn Bhd
Add1: Bayan Lepas Free Industrial Zone,Phase 3,Halaman Kampung Jawa
 Bayan Lepas
 Pulau Pinang
 11900
----- Customer 3 -----
CustomerCode: CUST00003
Name: Petronas Carigali Sdn. Bhd.
Add1: Tower 1, Petronas Twin Towers,Kuala Lumpur City Centre,
 Kuala Lumpur
 Wilayah Persekutuan
 50088
```

Comment: @user2479042 You should accept Brian Rogers' Answer, because it is complete and it works.

Comment: Actually I did it not sure what happened. I accepted it again.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I always start there; in fact I did for this answer.  Unfortunately, json2csharp doesn't handle the case where you need to use a dictionary for a series of objects with varying keys, as was the case here.  It will instead generate a separate class for each object in the series.  (And if the propery names are numeric, it will generate ugly names like `__invalid_type__1`.)  Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @user2479042 Did you really mean to change the accepted answer for this question?  The other answer does not seem to work as written.